# How do I get two vertical jQuery UI progress bars next to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have two progressbars using jQuery UI in single div (by subdividing the div). I also managed them to draw vertically using a modified version of the jQuery UI progressbar code (drawn from [this forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/verical-progress-bar)). But they don't get drawn next to each other as expected.

Here's the code where I'm setting them up:

```
function drawVBar(self,average,eid)
{
var mainid="#"+eid;
var target = $ ("#" + eid),
first= target.find(".first"),
second= target.find(".second");
if(!first[0])
{
    first= $("<div>").addClass("first").appendTo(target);
    second= $("<div>").addClass("second").appendTo(target);         
}
first.progressbar({value: self,orientation: 'vertical'});

second.progressbar({value: average,orientation: 'vertical'});
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I style them so that they show next to each other?

Comment: Could you also please post your markup?

Comment: @  Scruffy The Janitor, in markup i am just passing 3 things to drawVBar function it is
`code` <div id="p1">
<script>
 drawBar(30,70,"p1");
</script>
</div>

Comment: There are probably a number of ways to do what you want, but without a specific example of both the HTML and, more importantly, all of the relevant CSS, it is impossible to provide a definitive answer. Can you create an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are wrapped in a div, then you could try `float:left`, or possibly even `display:inline`. If you are floating them and it messes up your page layout, try wrapping them in a div with `overflow:auto`

```
function drawVBar(self,average,eid)
{
var mainid="#"+eid;
var target = $ ("#" + eid),
first= target.find(".first"),
second= target.find(".second");
if(!first[0])
{
    first= $("<div style='float:left'>").addClass("first").appendTo(target);
    second= $("<div style='float:left'>").addClass("second").appendTo(target);         
}
first.progressbar({value: self,orientation: 'vertical'});

second.progressbar({value: average,orientation: 'vertical'});
}
```

Comment: glad to help. you should also tick the check mark next to the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Actually the ans was right there... easy one. all i had to do is set css of both objs (first,second)

e.g to place second progress bar at any place

```
second.progressbar({value: average,orientation: 'vertical'});
second.css({"position":"absolute","left":"30px"});
```

and so on... for other css values